# Entity Framework : create a class with multiple relationships to another

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Kid
        {
            
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; } 
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public Date Time BirthDate { get; set; }
            public ProfilePhoto CurrentProfilePhoto { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<ProfilePhoto> ProfilePhotos { get; set; }
    }
 public class ProfilePhoto
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public byte[] PhotoData { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateUploaded { get; set; }
    
            public int KidID { get; set; }
            public Kid Kid { get; set; }
    }
```

every kid entity has multiple profile photos , but it may have or not a single current Profile photo.
On the other side every ProfilePhoto is related to one kid , and just one ProfilePhoto of that Kid can be the current profile photo.
How to represent these kind of relations Using DataAnnotations or FluentAPI(i prefer to use DataAnnotations if possible) in EntityFramework 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

There are three approaches you can use:

Option 1: Add a CurrentProfilePhotoId property to Kid as a FK to the CurrentProfilePhoto navigation property.

```
[ForeignKey("CurrentProfilePhoto")]
public int? CurrentProfilePhotoId { get; set; }
public virtual ProphilePhoto CurrentProfilePhoto { get; set; }
```

Option 2: Mark the CurrentProfilePhoto as `[NotMapped]` and calculate it client side from the ProfilePhotos collection:

```
[NotMapped]
public ProphilePhoto CurrentProfilePhoto
{
    get { return ProfilePhotos.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTaken).FirstOrDefault(); }
}
```

Option 3: Remove CurrentProfilePhoto from the entity and rely on projection to a ViewModel whenever the current photo is needed. I.e.

```
var kid = context.Kids
    .Where(x => x.Id == kidId)
    .Select(x => new KidDetailViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Name = x.LastName + ", " + x.FirstName,
        BirthDate = x.BirthDate,
        CurrentProfilePhoto = x.ProfilePhotos
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTaken)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    }).Single();
```

Option 1 is pretty simple, however there is no way to explicitly enforce that any photo referenced by CurrentProfilePhotoId is a photo for that Kid. It could accidentally be associated to a photo of any other record not associated to that Kid ID. It is recommended when using references like this that you set up a data sanity check job in the database to alert you if ever a Photo referenced by a CurrentPhotoId has a different Kid ID.

Option 2 ensures that the current photo is always associated to that kid, however you either need to remember to always eager load the entire ProfilePhotos collection when loading a Kid, or it will trigger a lazy-load of that collection to get that current photo.

Option 3 is my recommended approach to get accustomed to projection. This ensures only the photos from that kid are referenced, and it generates a query that only pulls back enough data to populate what you need at that particular time. In this example only one photo would be pulled back along with the necessary details from the Kid record.